# RAM, Memory cell and address

Tags: c++, memory, computer-science, ram

I am trying to get a sound understanding about how RAM works in most computers.
I am watching videos and reading online but haven't got a straight clear answer.

I just have two questions:

1. Is *Memory cell* the same as *memory address*? Is there a difference?
2. What is the smallest unit of addressable memory -> Here I am getting conflicting info, some say It is 1 byte, some say it is 1 bit.

In C++ byte seems to be the smallest data type.
What if I want to store a variable that either has the value 0 or 1, is there no data type that can store just 1 bit ?

I see even the boolean data type takes 1 byte, even though it could be just 0 or 1?

So would it be fair to say that the smallest unit of addressable memory is a byte and not a bit?

Comment: This question is a bunch of questions. Are you asking about how RAM works or how C++ works with memory? Because C++ does not care what is going on in RAM; it just has an expectation that memory works a certain way.

Comment: Its mainly to do with how RAM works, I am just using C++ to get practical experience I thought as it has memory management and I need to revise C++ anyway

Comment: I hear comments about memory address, cell and I am not sure exactly what they are

Comment: Okay, so in its basic, I just want to know what is a memory cell, memory address, do I need to know this as a computer scientist ? I just want to know the basics very well

Comment: I will edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: @theMyth: "*Its mainly to do with how RAM works, I am just using C++ to get practical experience I thought as it has memory management and I need to revise C++ anyway*" My point is that most programming languages do not care about what is going on inside the physical memory devices. It merely expects that if it writes data to an address, that value can be recovered later. The details are unimportant to the language.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. Okay but in C++ there is manual memory management, so If I later learn about memory overflow, buffer overflow, should I not know the fundamentals about how memory works ?

Comment: Background reading - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory continued reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode and finally where we are today https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: Thanks @RichardCritten , it has a lot of info. So basically after reading that in brief could I say a memory address is made up of memory cells ? I am reading the rest of it, Thanks

Comment: "should I not know the fundamentals about how memory works?" You should know the fundamentals of how to use memory. But you don't need to know how memory works at the electrical level. A librarian needs to know how to organize books, how to classify them, how to keep track of them, make sure the same book isn't checked out to two people at once. But a librarian doesn't need to know how a printing press works.

Comment: @theMyth: "*there is manual memory management, so If I later learn about memory overflow, buffer overflow, should I not know the fundamentals about how memory works ?*" How a RAM chip actually stores, maintains, and retrieves data? I couldn't tell you that, but I can tell you all about how the C++ object and memory model works. Both manual and automatic. You also don't have to be able to know how a car's transmission works to be able to drive one.

Comment: A memory cell is like a house.  The house can hold stuff and it has a location.  The location is the *address*.  So, the memory address is the location of the memory cell inside the computer.

Comment: The smallest amount of memory accessible depends on the processor.  Some processors allow for accessing bits in memory.  Other processors can only fetch a byte (uint8-t) as smallest units.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews And some (famously the PDP-11 and Alpha AXP) can't even fetch bytes. PDP-11 minimum access unit was a 36-bit word. Alpha AXP minimum access unit is 32-bit long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest addressable unit is a byte (in most current computers that you will come accross)

To set a variable to 0 or 1 will require that variable to be at least one byte. But you can use individual bits in one byte for different bits

You do that using bit fields in structs in c or by bit level operations on bytes (or larger)

Comment: Thanks, and then would it also be fair to say that the smallest addressable unit will have at least 8 memory cells ? As each memory cell stores 1 bit ?

Comment: @theMyth memory cell is not a well defined term in CS

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I dont really need to know what that is ?

Comment: @theMyth - professional developer of 45 years here, I never used the term in all that time

Comment: @theMyth have a read of [C++ Memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model)